# No Title Bar Android Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

In my application I want to use the Theme.NoTitleBar, but on the other hand I also don't want to loose the internal Theme of the Android OS.. I searched on the net and Found the following answer.. I have modified my styles.xml and added the following line of code..

Inside values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme"></style>
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>
```

Inside values-v11/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"></style>
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"></style>
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></style>
```

Inside values-v14/styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
<style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"></style>
```

In the **application** tag of the Manifest file I have added an attribute of:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
```

But when I try to run the code The images in my application gets Blurry.. But when I use the following tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

The images in the application comes in the correct form... But In this case I lose all the themes on the new Android OS..

Please help me how can I use NoTitleBar Theme without loosing the Images and the Native Theme..

Code for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainScreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/main_top_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/top_bar_title" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_bar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_top_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_nav_bar" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_bar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_bar1"
    android:background="@drawable/location_nav_bar" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/map_bar_bg" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/MapPointer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/map_pointer" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/MapSeperator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="|"
                android:textColor="#979ca0"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <com.pnf.myevent.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/DisplayLocation"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#adabad"
                android:textSize="12dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/RefreshBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/refresh_button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/MonthBtn"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/month_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TodayBtn"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/today_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/WeekBtn"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/week_button" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_bar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_bar2"
    android:background="@drawable/cal_nav_bar" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_arrow_button" />

    <com.pnf.myevent.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/CalTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CalNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/right_arrow_button" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_bar4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_bar3"
    android:background="#c8c9cc" >

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/container_bar4" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/CalendarList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#dedede"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Images Getting Blurry]

Comment: You don't loose the Android theme by setting no title bar. You are doing something wrong in your XML layout. Please post the layout so we can review that. Also is this happening for all Android platform versions? Or just a specific one

Comment: Its happening on all platforms. I have created folders of layout in red folder like layout-ldpi, layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi and layout-xhdpi and also having the drawable folders containing different images for different screens. The screen shot is taken from galaxy s3 but same is getting on the emulator

Comment: Can you post one of the layouts then? You don't need different layouts based on dpi unless you have some special case scenario.

Comment: @JaySoyer I have edited the post please have a look...

Comment: Ok. My next question is whether you are using drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc.  Which layout is that XML specifically for?

Comment: Yes I am using the drawable-mdpi, etc. This layout is using drawable-mdpi

Answer (score 30):

if you want the original style of your Ui to remain and the title bar to be removed with no effect on that, you have to remove the title bar in your activity rather than the manifest. leave the original theme style that you had in the manifest and in each activity that you want no title bar use `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` in the `oncreate()` method **before** `setcontentview()` like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ...
}
```

Comment: this works, but this is not the best solution, title bar blinking for some secod before disapeare

Comment: thnks it wokred for me..vot up

Comment: I used exectly the same lines in this exact order and yet I got the excpetion: 'android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content' - anyone knows why?

Answer (score 24):

To Hide the Action Bar add the below code in Values/Styles

```
<style name="CustomActivityThemeNoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml file add the below code in the required activity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.newbelievers.android.NBMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nbmenu"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActivityThemeNoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: "android:windowActionBar" requires API +11
So since my compatibility is +8, "android:windowNoTitle" did the trick
Thank you ;)

Answer (score 7):

In your manifest use:-

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

in styles.xml:-

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Surprisingly this works as yo desire, Using the same parent of AppBaseTheme in AppTheme does not.

Comment: Surprise surprise, nothing on this page worked for me. I suspect I shall have stop extending `ActionBarActivity` in favour of vanilla `Activity`. Even brutish kludges like `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` simply FC.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you changing android os inbuilt **theme**.

As per your activity Require You have to implements this way

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

as per `@arianoo` says you have to used this feature.

I think this is better way to **hide titlebar theme.**

Answer (score 2):

In your styles.xml, modify style "AppTheme" like

```
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` in manifest file's application tag to remove the title bar for whole application or put it in activity tag to remove the title bar from a single activity screen.

Comment: Wont this also modify the theme to an old style one?

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Would be "more correct" like this:  `requestWindowFeature( android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
`