# Android Activity name show in top of the apps

Tags: android

I am new in android programming.
Recently I have working in a android apps.
I notice that when I run my apps in my phone it shows Activity name in top of the apps.
Even if I go to my second activity it shows second activity name.
How I can stop it?
Please suggest me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No Title Bar Android Theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692808/no-title-bar-android-theme)

Comment: Do you want to hide ActionBar or you want to write you own title here?

Comment: You can remove that bar using two way one is using code and another by changing theme. If you want to remove it from full application use  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` in Manifest under application.

Answer (score 5):

Try this in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()`, it will remove that bar, and it is called `ActionBar`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to remove it from whole app, try this.

Open your AndroidManifest.xml file and add this in your `application` tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
```

Here you can use any variant as per your existing theme style like `Theme.Holo.Light` to `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` or `Theme.Holo.Dark.` to `Theme.Holo.Dark.NoActionBar` or `Theme.NoTitleBar` if you don't have any custom theme as suggeted by Aniruddha.

Check this SO answer if you have custom theme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10318745/1765573

Comment: you need to do no.theme in the activity tag in the manifest otherwise you still will have a title flash at application startup.

Comment: @Aniruddha: thanks for pointing out, yes it will be shown for a moment on start up if you add it from java file. I edited my answer and add the code for AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the title, for that you need to add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView()` in activity.

And you need to do no.theme in the activity tag in the manifest otherwise you still will have a title flash at application startup.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove title bar from every activity then you can do the following

```
<application android:name=".AppName" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: ,shall we put this line Master Activity instead of every Activity what you think about it ?

Comment: This is i know but i clearly asking about above line ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what You mean by Activity name. Could You show us what You mean? Usually, it is normal that on every app, the app name is above. This is defined in the manifest.xml like this:

```
<activity        
    android:label="@string/app_name" <--this is the name You can change
                       .
                       .
                       .
</activity>
```

To avoid displaying this name, You can set some flags after onCreate in Your activities:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line in the activities you want inside manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

To change that to the app's name or any other name of your choice, open AndroidManifest.xml file of your application, there for every activity, you will find such pieces of code

```
<activity></activity> OR <activity android:name=".activityname" />
```

change that to-->
suppose your activity name is 'abc'

```
<activity>
android:name=".abc"
android:label="whatever name you want"
</activity>
```

you can either hard-code the strings or use them from string.xml file