# Activity with duplicate toolbar

Tags: java, android

I have an initial basic activity that will serve as login screen (this screen has a common bar, only with the name of the application, without the drawer navigation option), when clicking the enter button on this screen, the user is directed to the activity main, in it I want to put the drawer navigation option with a toggle icon. But if I add a toolbar, the toolbar gets duplicated, how can I solve this?

```
Toolbar toolbarPrincipal = findViewById(R.id.toolbarPrincipal);

DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbarPrincipal, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Title Bar Android Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692808/no-title-bar-android-theme)

Comment: @MikeM. agreed. the question just does not indicate if it is `v4` or `v7`... or even `androidx` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle

Comment: @MartinZeitler It's either v7, or androidx, neither of which are deprecated. There is no v4 constructor that takes a `Toolbar`.

Comment: @MikeM. I'd blame it on my new noob hat. however, it basically still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all toolbar related code.

01.add style

```
<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
</style>
```

02.create xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
style="@style/HeaderBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:textSize="@dimen/toolbar_text_size"
android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
android:background="#234E6F"
app:contentInsetStart="5dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="10dp"
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText" />
```

03.add this in your activity xml file

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
```

04.Finally add this your activity

```
   Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Leave Menu List");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the NoActionBar styles for your activity with drawer.

1. Go to values styles and add new style that extends one of the NoActionBar styles.
2. In your manifest, set appropriate theme for appropriate activity

Follow this documentation for more info onstyles and themes.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you have added toolbar and you also have actionbar theme.

so set NoactionBar theme in your Style.xml and Activity tag in Manifest File. then you can use Toolbar.